# Batch printing from Unity? Shell?

Tags: printing, automation

Is there a way to batch print some files (PDFs)?

Comment: You can use the lpr command. You can print multiple files using e.g. lpr * in a folder. If the order is important, you could write a shell script which prints the files e.g. ordered by filename, if lpr does not do that automatically. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your comment looks like an answer, why not make it one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(From comment above by Michael K):

> You can use the lpr command. You can print multiple files using e.g.
>   lpr * in a folder. If the order is important, you could write a shell
>   script which prints the files e.g. ordered by filename, if lpr does
>   not do that automatically. Hope this helps